# Is it possible to return each value instead of an array from array.filter method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm using a combination of .forEach() and .filter() array methods to filter some data. Because array.filter() returns a new array and I end up with a multi-dimensional array in the end, I have to use an extra coding step.

Is there an obvious solution I don't see here?

```
// array with all game results
var allGames = [
  {id: 1, commander: 'Kerrigan', map: 'Rifts to Korhal', win: true},
  {id: 1, commander: 'Kerrigan', map: 'Rifts to Korhal', win: true},
  {id: 2, commander: 'Artanis', map: 'Void Thrashing', win: false},
  {id: 3, commander: 'Raynor', map: 'Dead of Night', win: true},
  {id: 4, commander: 'Alarak', map: 'Void Launch', win: true},
  {id: 5, commander: 'Dehaka', map: 'Void Launch', win: false},
  {id: 6, commander: 'Swann', map: 'Malwarfare', win: true},
  {id: 7, commander: 'Nova', map: 'Rifts to Korhal', win: true}
];

// currently selected commanders in stats window
var activeCommander = ['Kerrigan', 'Raynor', 'Nova'];

function filterGames(stats) {

  let newStats = new Array();

  activeCommander.forEach((item) => {
    // my first attempt was this, but it creates a multi-dimensional Array
    // newStats.push(stats.filter((event) => event.commander === item));

    // my workaround. using a temp array and later cycle thru
    // I don't like this extra step, is there a way to do it better?
    let temp = stats.filter((event) => event.commander === item);
    temp.forEach((tempItem)=> {
      newStats.push(tempItem);
    });
  });

  return newStats;

}

let result = filterGames(allGames);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If `commander` is the primary means by which an item is chosen, instead of an Array, I'd use a `Map` of commander name to each object for fast and simple lookup.

Answer (score 3):

Filter the `stats` array directly:

```
function filterGames(stats) {
    return stats.filter(s => activeCommander.some(a => a === s.commander));
}
```

```js
// array with all game results
var allGames = [
  {id: 1, commander: 'Kerrigan', map: 'Rifts to Korhal', win: true},
  {id: 1, commander: 'Kerrigan', map: 'Rifts to Korhal', win: true},
  {id: 2, commander: 'Artanis', map: 'Void Thrashing', win: false},
  {id: 3, commander: 'Raynor', map: 'Dead of Night', win: true},
  {id: 4, commander: 'Alarak', map: 'Void Launch', win: true},
  {id: 5, commander: 'Dehaka', map: 'Void Launch', win: false},
  {id: 6, commander: 'Swann', map: 'Malwarfare', win: true},
  {id: 7, commander: 'Nova', map: 'Rifts to Korhal', win: true},
];

// currently selected commanders in stats window
var activeCommander = ['Kerrigan', 'Raynor', 'Nova'];

function filterGames(stats) {
 return stats.filter(s => activeCommander.some(a => a === s.commander));
}

let result = filterGames(allGames);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use filter directly with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
function filterGames(stats) {
  return stats.filter(game => activeCommander.includes(game.commander))
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about .include() or .some(). Guess I need to take a closer look at array methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf function, it has good support in browsers and works well

```
function filterGames(stats) {
    return stats.filter(s => activeCommander.indexOf(s.commander) >= 0);
}
```